# how to write an array literal notation in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

how to write an array literal notation in JS?

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.prop = 'test';
```

i've already tried this, but it logs undefined value.

```
var myArray = [prop='test'];
console.log(myArray.prop);
```

Comment: Please take a tour of the basics first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

The array literal is:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

You cannot use keys in this, because Javascript arrays **do not have string keys**. They're numerically indexed lists. Setting a property on an array object does not do what you think it does.

What you're looking for is an *object literal*:

```
{ foo : 'bar', baz : 42 }
```

Comment: ahh, thanks for the help, i'm still learning the basic, and btw i got this from http://jsfiddle.net/javascriptenlightenment/RuQfJ/

Comment: Unless that's an example of what not to do/unexpected results, you should not follow that tutorial/site/whateverthatisfrom anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript cannot have string indices... they must be numbers.  What you're looking for in your case is an object.

```
var myObject = {
    prop: 'test'
}
```